# Windows 10 Event Logging Directly to OS Event Log/Manager

Tags: c#, logging, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm looking to build in a Logging solution into my Windows Universal Application and am currently using System.Diagnostics to create a FileLoggingSession and a channel to which I'm logging messages. Then when my application is closed I save that session to a file which I can then import and view in the Windows Event Viewer manually. (I've also looked at 3rd party logging solutions that manage the file for me, such as NLog and MetroLog, but NLog doesn't support UWP yet and I could never configure MetroLog to work)

What I'd like to do is to simply write directly to the Windows 10 Application Event Logs so I don't have to manage the file. How do I do this? In non-UWP it seems that System.Diagnostics.EventLog was what you would use for this, but it is unavailable in UWP.

Comment: Is System.Diagnostics.TraceListener available?  You might be able to use a Trace/TraceSource/TraceListener to write to the EventLog.

Comment: @khargoosh It doesn't look like it is available, no. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: I'm not so sure, but will [LoggingSession class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.loggingsession.aspx) meet your expect? Unlike `FileLoggingSession`, this class sends logged messages to disk on-demand, and this happens when there's a problem and the immediate history of in-memory messages is needed for analysis.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT No unfortunately LoggingSession isn't really what I'm looking for. I'd really like to write directly to the Windows Event Log as the log aggregator used in our production environment can be configured to read from there. Alternatively if you know of a way I can write to a .txt file instead of a .etl that also works.

Comment: TextWriterTraceListener is also apparently not available on UWP so I am also looking for a way to redirect Debug.WriteLine to a file.